# how to return the requested shape using linq?

Tags: c#

How to create that rectangle in a multi-line string and return 
it?
You must use '*' character to make that rectangle. The width will be the number of stars in each line, and the height will be the number of lines.

> **Attention:**  You can only use Enumerable and Linq to generate your
>   answer. Do not use 'for' loop in your answer.

Example:  width = 10, height = 5

Result:

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: Example:width = 10, height = 5
Result: 

**********
**********
**********
**********
**********

Comment: What have you tried yet? StackOverflow is not a place to ask to write code for your homework

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("*", w)) + "\n", h)));`

Comment: `StackOverFlow.com != HomeworkService.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
int width = 10, height = 5;
IEnumerable<string> lines = Enumerable.Repeat(new string('*', width), height);
```

This generates a collection of strings representing the lines of the rectangle.

Edit: To return a string of the box, you can use `String.Join()`.

```
public string GetStarBox(int width, int height)
{
    IEnumerable<string> lines = Enumerable.Repeat(new string('*', width), height);
    return String.Join(lines, '\n');
}
```

`String.Join()` groups a collection of strings into a single string, seperated by a newline (`\n`) element in this case.

Another edit:

This will explain the code a bit more, step by step.
Let's first of all look at this line:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = Enumerable.Repeat(new string('*', width), height);
```

`IEnumerable<T>` represents a sort of 'collection' of data of the specified type `T`, which is used to store the individual lines of the rectangle.

`Enumerable.Repeat(TResult, Int32)` returns a new IEnumerable filled with a certain number of repeating `TResults`, specified by the `Int32` parameter.

The constructor of the string with the parameters `char` and `int` creates a new string instance with the `char` parameter being repeated as many times as the `int` parameter specifies.

So, in essence, you are:

1. Creating a new string of `*` characters, repeated for `width` times.
2. Repeating the same string for `height` times, since the width of the rectangle won't change across lines.
3. Storing the result in an `IEnumerable` to store the lines (since they both derive from `IEnumerable`, an array and a `System.Collections.Generic.List` will work aswell).
4. Then *joining* these strings together in a single string, with the individual lines seperated by a newline (`\n`) character.

Comment: Although your answer might be correct, I down vote since OP has not shown any effort.

Comment: Yeah that's true ... should I delete my answer ..?

Comment: We can see where it goes, maybe the post will be deleted although there are not a lot of moderators at the moment.

Comment: public static string GetStarBox(int width, int height) 
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException(); 
} // the method returns a string value.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers, I think it will be easy to modify the return as a string.

Comment: Thanks @Ian H   :) , I am still viewing tutorials about linq. I am overwhelmed with how many questions in the training.

Comment: @RoyGuzman Linq is a reaaaally big topic to learn about, but it gets extremely useful when you want to keep your code clean and quick. Best of luck to you!

Comment: @IanH.: Please take a look at this post for future cases: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @IanH.: If you edit this post a bit I can revert my down-vote; see DonaldDucks reasoning (never thought saying that) for details.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the reference, I will remember it, even though the OP has stated that it is not for homework. I edited my answer to include a more detailed description of the answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, Ian, I am actually a student but this is not for homework I finished the exams for my third year on the 7th June. this is  2 weeks training course for my job. I study computing science and information technology in the open university. last year we studied java extensively but nothing prepared me for c# or LINQ, so those 2 weeks are book camp to learn as much as I can about c#, I am really doing the best I can. regards Roy

Comment: @RoyGuzman: You might want to check out this site: http://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/quantifiers/All It contains almost all linq operations, lambda style.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
        {
            var w = 10;
            var h = 5;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("*", w)) + "\n", h)));
        }
}
```

Comment: Although your answer might be correct, I down vote since OP has not shown any effort.

Comment: Yeah that's true ... should I delete my answer ..?

Comment: We can see where it goes, maybe the post will be deleted although there are not a lot of moderators at the moment.

Comment: don't delete the answers guys, they definitely helped.

Comment: this is the question and the method header

Comment: @Mardoxx I really like the fact that you copy pasted my comment, just as Stefan did.

Comment: this is not for homework. I am taking the summer to learn c#, and I am having a difficult time with linq. this is free training provided by the company I work for.

Comment: @Stefan If the question is bad, downvote the question, not the answer. It's perfectly acceptable to post good answers to bad questions, [there is even a badge for that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal).

Comment: @Mardoxx While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: Even better, there is a meta post about this which seems not to be in line with my actions. Nevertheless it's good to mention that OP would be better off by being challenged to show some effort. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823

Comment: @Mardoxx: Please take a look at this post for future cases: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Mardoxx: If you edit this post a bit I can revert my down-vote; see DonaldDucks reasoning (never thought saying that) for details.